# How to show that the functionals given form a basis for the dual space.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I've done part $(a)$, but not sure about part $(b)$. If I understand the quetion correctly, then if $f$ is just a general polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$, then $E_{x_0},\ldots,E_{x_n}$ are just $f(x_0),\ldots,f(x_n)$, but then it seems to me like they might not be linearly independent, since we can have for example $x_0,x_1$ being roots of $f$, and then $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$ and we don't have linear independence. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for some $a_i\in\mathbb{F}$,

$$
E=a_0E_{x_0}+\cdots+a_nE_{x_n}=0
$$

Note that above equality displays **functional equality** meaning that the functional defined by the sum of functionals is just a $0$ functional. Thus we want to show that $a_i$ are $0$ under these conditoins.

There is a obvious way to proceed:

Let $p_i(x)=(x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})\cdots (x-x_n) \in \mathcal{P}_n$

What happens if you apply $E$ to $p_i$?

Edit: I don't see why your particular example might imply that $E_{x_i}$ are linearly dependent, for linear independence we always require

$$
E=0 \implies a_i=0 \;\; \forall i
$$

Claiming $E=0$ is much stronger than just claiming $E(p)=0$ for some $p\in \mathcal{P}_n$. $E=0$ means $E(p)=0$ for all $p$.

Comment: I think where I went wrong is that I didn't realise that E=a0Ex0+⋯+anExn=0 should be true for any function f. Thank you very much!